# Conversion of string to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read from the following file my data, and create a table.

```
         tracks=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\demet\\Desktop\\Internship\\scripts\\tracks-rainy.csv')
```

Yet when I print for instance an element instead of obtaining a float a get a string.

```
         print(tracks.iloc[track_id][3][0])
```

What should I add to my project.

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for `read_csv`? In particular, does the `dtype` parameter seem useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Comment: @isle_of_gods Thank you very much. Everything works smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

`tracks=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\demet\\Desktop\\Internship\\scripts\\tracks-rainy.csv', dtype={'track_id':'Float64'})`

Which tell pandas to interpret the column as Float. (As Karl Knechtel said)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to initiate the conversion when reading the csv file, you can always do list comprehension with a `float` conversion.

```
tracks['track_id'] = [float(i) for i in tracks['track_id']]
```